# Хочу создать randomizer.py вместо randomizer.ui, но вылазит ошибка Python PySide2 5.14.0

Tags: python, cmd, pyside2

Вылазит много ошибок с разными файлами .dell. Я переустановил PySide2, но ничего не изменилось  - Не удается продолжить выполнение кода, поскольку система не обнаружила MSVCP140.dll. Для устранения этой проблемы попробуйте переустановить программу.

Comment: какой командой пользовались?

Comment: pyside-uic "Путь(в конце test.ui)" -x -o "Путь(превращаешь test.py)"

Comment: попробуйте "путь до питон\Python 3.7\Scripts\pyside2-uic.exe" "путь до файла\файл.ui" -o "путь до нового файла\файл.py"

Comment: Файл создался, но в файле много ошибок (30). Из за from import

Comment: каких например?

Comment: Это первая
 "No name 'QCoreApplication' in module 'PySide2.QtCore'

Comment: попробуйте лучше PyQt5, а не PySide2

Comment: Такая же ошибка, вместо PySide2 добавил PyQt5 - "No name 'QCoreApplication' in module 'PyQt5.QtCore'

Comment: хм, а корректно ли установлен `PyQt5`? я бы порекомендовал как ультимативное решение переустановить модудь pyqt5